# Задача на бинарный поиск

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Всем привет. Помогите решить задачу на бинарный поиск.

**Условие:**
В этой задаче вам нужно будет несколько раз находить в отсортированном массиве первое число, которое больше числа из запроса.

**Входные данные:**
В первой строке записаны два целых числа nn, mm (1 <= m, n <= 2 * 10^5) - размер массива и количество запросов.

Во второй строке записаны nn целых чисел в неубывающем порядке, каждое по модулю не превышает 10^. Эти числа образуют данный массив.

В следующих mm строках даны числа запросов, по одному в строке.

**Выходные данные:**
Для каждого запроса выведите самое маленькое число в массиве, которое больше данного. Если такого числа нет, вместо него выведите <> (без кавычек).

**Sample Input:**
10 10 
-18 -15 -6 -4 -1 3 5 13 15 16
3
-7
13
-2
-4
9
-20
8
16
-17

**Sample Output:**
5
-6
15
-1
-1
13
-18
13
NO SOLUTION
-15

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Используй встроенный upper_bound
Документация и примеры использования:
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/upper_bound-in-cpp/amp/

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)